# topological transversal and differential transversal

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-topology

Given a smooth vector fied on the two-torus, suppose it has a topological transversal, i.e. there exists a closed curve that intersects each integral curve of the vector field, does it imply that there exists a differential transversal, i.e. there exists a $C^1$ closed curve that is transverse to every integral curve?

Comment: Are you assuming the field never vanishes? If not, do the equilibrium points count as (degenerate) integral curves? Just because it is easy to make a smooth flow with one equilibrium point $x_0$ on the torus and a closed curve that intersects each integral curve  included $x_0$, but of course no curve can be transverse at $x_0$ in the differential sense.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are on the 2-torus, I guess that you assume that your vector field does not vanish. You seem to give a definition of "topological transversal"; your definition is too large; there is always a closed continuous Peano curve filling the 2-torus! And there is always a smooth simple closed curve $C$ meeting every integral curve.

There is a known notion of "topological transversality"; it means that at every point $x$ of your curve $C$ there is a local topological chart
$\phi:U(\subset T^2)\to V(\subset R^2)$ sending $x$ to $0$ and $C$ to $R\times 0$ and the integral curve through $x$ to $0\times R$. With this definition, the existence of a topological total closed transversal implies the existence of a $C^1$ simple closed curve transverse (in the usual sense) to the vector field and meeting every integral curve. Indeed, both are equivalent to the absence of "plane Reeb components".

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that the closed curve does not intersect any zero of the vector field, the answer is yes, I think. Just cover your closed transversal by a finite number of flow boxes, and build a smooth transversal, successively in each flow box.